# Trying to make a loop which counts letters but not spaces

Tags: c, increment, isalpha

I am trying to construct a simple programme which counts the number of letters in a user's input. My idea was to use a `for` loop which would loop for each letter in a string, increment a counter, and return the final counter total at the end. However, I do not want the programme to count spaces- I attempted to use the `isalpha` function to do this- but I seem to be formatting it incorrectly. Also, the way I tried to make the counter NOT increment for a space was with `c = c`, however, this also seems to be incorrect. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
int c = 0;

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Input:  ");
    printf("Output: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
    if( s[i] (isalpha))
        {
        c++;
        }
    else
        {
        c = c;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", c);
}
```

Comment: When asking questions, include a [mre]. That means you should include **complete** source code that reproduces the problem. Your code uses `string`, which is not a standard C identifier. Likely, you are working on Harvard’s CS50 course, and your actual text contains a line like `#include "cs50.h"`. You should show this in the source code provided in a question.

Comment: Never describe a problem as “but I seem to be formatting it incorrectly.” State what error message or undesired behavior you are observing. State what behavior you desire instead. State what you do that results in the undesired behavior. That may be “I compile the source code shown here, and the result is the compiler prints a message “xyz,” but I want the program to compile with no errors.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your advice, I shall make sure to follow these guidelines in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isalpha` is effectively a function call. (It is a function call or a function-like macro.) A function call is written as `name()`, `name(argument)`, or `name(argument,…)` according to whether it is passing zero, one, or more arguments. `isalpha` takes a single argument. That argument should be an `unsigned char` value. So you can call it as `isalpha((unsigned char) s[i])`. Your `if` statement should look like:

```
if (isalpha((unsigned char) s[i]))
```

Your program should also contain `#include <ctype.h>` to include the header that declares `isalpha`.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know what I need to do in order to make the counter not increment for spaces?

Comment: @BlueKhakis: You do not need to do anything in order for the counter not to increment. The braces of the `else` part can be empty, like `else { }`, or you can omit the `else` part entirely. Again, we do not know what problem you had with this because you did not say how it “seems to be incorrect.” We do not know if that means you got an error message from the compiler, or which message, or whether the program did not work the way you want, or whether there was some other problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will be more diligent in describing future questions.

Answer (score 0):

This record

```
s[i] (isalpha)
```

is incorrect and does not make a sense.

What you need is the following

```
size_t c = 0;

for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    if( isalpha( ( unsigned char )s[i] ) ) ++c;
}
printf("c = %zu\n", c );
```

Pay attention to that the function `isalpha` is declared in the header `<ctype.h>` that you have to include.

Comment: Hi Vlad, can you explain what the "size_t" is doing in the code you posted?

Comment: @BlueKhakis: `size_t` is an unsigned integer type that’s often used to represent array indices.